# Table overflowing div, too long page

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a problem with the length of my page: I want it to be as long as the main table, while at the moment the page overflows that lenght.

This is my link, please ignore all the deprecated things like center and so on: https://bottegalarosabianca.altervista.org/sitobottega/lunghidonna.html

And this is what I don't want to show:

[all this blank space I'd like it to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYQP7.png)

I suppose the problem is somewhere here:

```
     thumbnail {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

thumbnail:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  z-index: 40;
}
    
thumbnail span{
      position: absolute;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px dashed gray;
visibility: hidden;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
width: 410px;
}

thumbnail span img{
border-width: 0;
padding: 2px;
}

thumbnail:hover span{
visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
top: 500px;
left: 1000px;
}
```

Because if I cut this part, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

use 50% instead of writing pixels
exp:

```
div.box-inner{
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
scrollbar-width: none;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).